# Adjusting three variables with slider HTML5 CANVAS JS

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas

I have a slider that needs to adjust 3 variables.
The slider min val is 0, max is 100.

What is the math behind adjusting the variables accordingly as the slider is moved?

See images...

Any help appreciated!!

[image: slider value at 0]
[image: slider value at 50]
[image: slider value at 100]
[image: slider value at 75]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about canvases but if you ask about just only the math that is easy:

If the sliders value is X:

A = 25 + max(50 - X, 0) / 2

B = 50 - abs(50 - X) / 2

C = 25 + max(X - 50, 0) /2

In javascript there is Math.max() and Math.abs() so a method for calculating this is:

```
function calculate(slidervalue) {
    var res = [];
    res['a'] = 25 + Math.max(50 - slidervalue, 0) / 2;
    res['b'] = 50 - Math.abs(50 - slidervalue) / 2;
    res['c'] = 25 + Math.max(slidervalue - 50, 0) /2;
    return res;
}
```

Of course you could make an object for the result or do whatever you want with it, it's just sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand your requirements correctly from your drawings.

- When the slider is at exactly at `min`: A=50, B=25, C=25
- When the slider is at exactly at `max`: A=25, B=25, C=50
- When the slider is exactly at 50%: A=25, B=50, C=25
- When the slider is somewhere between `min` and 50%, A and B should be between 25 and 50 depending on the distance from the slider value to `min` and 50% respectively
- When the slider is somewhere between `max`and 50%, B and C should be between 25 and 50 depending on the distance from the slider value to `max` and 50% respectively

Try this:

```
// Assuming the variable value is already set
var a = 25, b = 25, c = 25;
if (value < 50) {
    a = 25 + (50 - value) / 2;
    b = 25 + (value) / 2;
}
else {
    b = 25 + (100 - value) / 2;
    c = 25 + (value - 50) / 2;
}
```

Checkpoints:

```
// value = 0:
a = 25 + (50 - 0) / 2; // 25 + 50 / 2 = 25 + 25 = 50
b = 25 + (0) / 2; // 25 + 0 = 25
c = 25;

// value = 50:
b = 25 + (100 - 50) / 2; // 25 + 50 / 2 = 25 + 25 = 50
c = 25 + (50 - 50) / 2; // 25 + 0 = 25
a = 25;

// value = 100:
b = 25 + (100 - 100) / 2; // 25 + 0 / 2 = 25
c = 25 + (100 - 50) / 2; // 25 + 50 / 2 = 25 + 25 = 50
a = 25;

// value = 75:
b = 25 + (100 - 75) / 2; // 25 + 25 / 2 = 25 + 12.5 = 37.5
c = 25 + (75 - 100) / 2; // 25 + 25 / 2 = 25 + 12.5 = 37.5
```